# I can't receive broadcast on battery state change?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, battery

I am having the exact same problem as this post: [Battery broadcast receiver doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582539/battery-broadcast-receiver-doesnt-work). But it seems no one has answered that question.

Here is my BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class BatteryLevelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v("plugg", "plug change fired");
    Toast.makeText(context, " plug change fired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

And here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".ReceversAndServices.BatteryLevelReceiver">
               <intent-filter android:priority="900">
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />

               </intent-filter>
           </receiver>

           <receiver android:name=".ReceversAndServices.BatteryLevelReceiver">
               <intent-filter android:priority="900">
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
               </intent-filter>
           </receiver>
```

I have also added this line to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
```

But still no success!

I would really appreciate if someone could advise me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [the documentation for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED):

> You can not receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver(). See ACTION_BATTERY_LOW, ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY, ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED, and ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED for distinct battery-related broadcasts that are sent and can be received through manifest receivers.

There you have it: you must explicitly register for it from your Java code.

Comment: thanks Darshan, but I want to run a service only when the battery is low or it is plugged in. Could you please tell me how should I do that?

Comment: If those are the only two events you care about, then you don't need `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` at all, and you'll be fine registering for them in the manifest. The broadcast for being plugged in is `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`. Both actions can be under the same `intent-filter`, you don't need to set a priority, and you don't need the `BATTERY_STATS` permission.

Answer (score 2):

I just followed the Android Developer Guide's on [Monitoring the Battery Level and Charging State](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) and had immediate success. If BatteryLevelReceiver is it's own class then I would recommend:

```
<receiver android:name=".BatteryLevelReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="900">
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Addition**

I'm willing to guess that you wrote BatteryLevelReceiver as a nested class in ReceversAndServices. According to [Receiver as inner class in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3608955/1267661), you cannot do that with non-static classes. You could make BatteryLevelReceiver a static class and register the receiver in onResume(), but then your app will need to be running to catch the events... Move your receiver to a separate class and register these Intents:

```
<receiver android:name=".BatteryLevelReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="900">
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

(Not BATTERY_CHANGED as Darshan Computing pointed out.)

Comment: You had immediate success receiving `BATTERY_LOW`, but you'll never receive `BATTERY_CHANGED` that way.

Comment: Thanks Sam, but as soon as I add static to it, I get error :(

Comment: @Kevin_Dingo Yes, I took a guess at what you were trying to do. I realized my mistake and was writing an update. If you are still getting errors, please add more detail to your question and the logcat errors.

Comment: @Sam although this receiver will be fired automatically, is it registering that broadcast receiver automatically? If so, do we need to unregistered it? I am supposing,  if we need to monitor the battery level we should not unregistered, so is there any downside if we don't unregistered?

Comment: @DarshanRivkaWhittle what is the best way to get my app to be started by android when the battery is fully charged?

Comment: @user3760100 There's no broadcast specifically for a fully charged battery, so you'll have to register for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` and decide yourself in that receiver if the battery is fully charged.  (Note that there's often a difference between the status `BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL` and being at 100% charge.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the battery receiver class not as a subclass of another one but as a seperate class in your project.

Also try using Context.registerReceiver() method explicitly in your code and do not forget to unregister it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29