# Android - service running in the background

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast, background-service

I want to call a method every time when the battery goes to 50%, even when the app is closed or the screen is turned off.
I tried Service and BroadcastReceiver but when I remove the app from recent apps list the Service is stopped and I doe't get calls of this method anymore.
How can I save it in backgroud?

Comment: Are you registering the receiver in your manifest?  Can you post relevant parts of your BroadcastReceiver, Service and AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Just looked at your related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257310/android-keep-broadcastreceiver-in-background.. Are you returning `Service.START_STICKY` from your service's `onStartCommand()` implementation?  This tells the system to restart your service any time it is killed.

Comment: Yes, I did it, but the service is stopped when I remove the app from recent apps.

Comment: Are you testing this on a device running KitKat?  If so take a look here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/H-DSQ4-tiac indications there is a bug in KitKat that kills sticky services of apps removed from recent task list.

Comment: Yes, I use KitKat. Does this bug happen on older versions?

Comment: Edit, Looks like it could be present in Jelly Bean as well as KitKat.  See answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there was a bug introduced with KitKat (**EDIT:** and Jelly Bean?) which prevents sticky services from being restarted when an app is swiped away from the recent apps list. see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/H-DSQ4-tiac

This workaround, provided in the above link by user [Musikant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624109/muzikant), should resolve the issue with devices running KitKat.  Implement the following in your `Service` class:

```
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
        restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

        PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.setExact(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
                restartServicePendingIntent);

        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }
```

See [START_STICKY does not work on Android KitKat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636330/start-sticky-does-not-work-on-android-kitkat-edit-and-jelly-bean) for other possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution I get for this:-

even though all the suggested answers on Stack overflow for the same question ,if doesnot help you in any way read this:
this just happens in some devices not in all and if this is happening with your app only in that particular device **please see the autostart permission for your app is granted or not under Settings.**
because

> brodcast are still delivered to our app but without the permission
>   granted for autostart app wont come to foreground

.