# Android make vibrate from background

Tags: java, android

I use the code below to make the phone vibrate when I receive a SMS with a specific text. But the phone vibrate only if the app is running.
How can I make the phone vibrate even when the app is closed ?

Manifest Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

SMSReceiver.java

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "SmdReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();

        if (myBundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                String body = message.getMessageBody();
                if (body == "test") {
                    Log.d(TAG, "vibrate"); // is print in the console
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(duration, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                    } else {
                        v.vibrate(duration); //deprecated in API 26
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to start a `Intent Service` and call `vibrate` from it, but it doesn't work. I think vibrate simply not work if the app is closed. The [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator) : "If your process exits, any vibration you started will stop."

Comment: I add a empty service that run in background with `startForeground` and it's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android tend to kill background apps, especially customization like MIUI. To avoid this you need, for example, to attach the worker process to a permanent notification. So that the system won't kill the app.

There are other ways to keep the app running like [services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) and [background processing](https://developer.android.com/guide/background).

For more details follow [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background).

And this is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257310/android-keep-broadcastreceiver-in-background) for something similar.