# SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am trying to develop a widget which showing Battery Temperature. when i am registering a broadcast Receiver with `android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED`

it shows some error like this.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED from pid=-1, uid=10058
```

As far as i know there is no need of permission for broadcast .  If it is in the case of an activity. it is working properly.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.BATTERY");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: show the code how you register

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski : please check the code.

Comment: Check this url if it solves your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277302/i-cant-receive-broadcast-on-battery-state-change

Comment: why would you even want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> As far as i know there is no need of permission for broadcast

Yes, there is. You are *sending* the broadcast. And, quoting [the documentation for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED):

> This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

You are not the system; you cannot send this broadcast.

I have no idea why you are creating a `PendingIntent` that is trying to send this broadcast, but you will need to do something else instead. If your objective is to trigger your `BroadcastReceiver` from a tap on your app widget, where that receiver *also* happens to listen to `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`, then just use an explicit `Intent` identifying the receiver when creating your `PendingIntent`:

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(this, YourReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```